# MySQL select rows from a table where column is linked to another column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 'Reslookup' table in which, I want to select Employees who is reporting to another ReportingID.

Here is a simplified version of my table with content:

```
Emp_NO   Name    ReportingID
531       A         16
1572      B         531
1032      C         1572
and so..on..
```

`Now, If I select ReportingID = 16 (in where condition), then Employees 531,1572,1032 should fetch,`

`Similarly, If I select ReportingID = 531 (in where condition), then Employees 1572,1032 should fetch,`

`Similarly, If I select ReportingID = 1572 (in where condition), then Employees 1032 should fetch`

Is there any solution??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
select Emp_No, Name, ReportingID
from Reslookup as t1
where ReportingID = 16
      or exists 
       (   select * 
           from Reslookup as t2
           where Emp_No = t1.ReportingID 
           and 
             (
                ReportingID = 16 
                or exists 
                 ( 
                    select * 
                    from Reslookup as t3
                    where Emp_No = t2.ReportingID 
                    and ReportingID = 16
                 )                 
              ) 
        )
```

You have to pass `ReportingID`, here I have given it as 16. So this will returns three rows.

Comment: This will give you the hierarchy up to 3 levels only like 531,1572,1032..... suppose you have one more row in table where "2034    D  1032" then it will not return the 4th level "2034"

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved as below:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rid SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
SELECT @rid:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Emp_NO SEPARATOR ',') FROM EMP 
             WHERE ReportingID IN (@rid)) AS rid FROM EMP
JOIN
(SELECT @rid:=16)tmp
WHERE ReportingID IN (@rid)) a;
```

Demo link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5be043/1

Table Schema and Data:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    `Emp_NO` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReportingID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `EMP` VALUES(531,'A',16);
INSERT INTO `EMP` VALUES(1572,'B',531);
INSERT INTO `EMP` VALUES(1032,'C',1572);
```

To get the data in tabualr format:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @rid:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Emp_NO SEPARATOR ',') FROM EMP 
         WHERE ReportingID IN (@rid)) AS rid, NAME FROM EMP
JOIN
(SELECT @rid:=16)tmp
WHERE ReportingID IN (@rid)) a;
```

Comment: @Anil Kumar Reddy, Can you please check given table and data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand but it looks like you need a `WHERE` clause in your query.

Try this:

```
SELECT Emp_NO, Name, ReportingID
FROM Reslookup
WHERE ReportingID = <desired ID>
```

Comment: You can try without where clause also

Comment: As per your query, I can only get one result..which is incorrect

Comment: You want to know if there is an alternative to using a `WHERE` clause?